# WPF using SaveFileDialog in MVVM

Tags: wpf, file, mvvm, dialog, save

I'm struggling with using SaveFileDialog in MVVM.

I'm using RelayCommand class and launch **SaveAsFileCommand**. Within the SaveAsFileCommand, using lambda expression I split two arguments to have:

Instance of **RichTextBox** control and  targeted path (**filePath**)

Then I call DataIO.SaveAsFile(arguments[0], arguments[1]), using above arguments.

To create the **SaveDialogBox** in the View Layer I'm using 3 classes:
**DialogBox**, **FileDialogBox** and **SaveFileDialogBox**

In the XAML I create the SaveDialogBox and try to call **SaveAsFileCommand** using **MultiBinding** to pass those two Command Parameters.

To show the **SaveDialogBox** I use the button which is bindded to **SaveDialogBox**

***The problem is***: At this place the compiler complains that it can't execute multibinding for my SaveDialogBox because of being non-DependencyObject and non-DependencyProperty.
How can I solve that problem and correctly save the file using that `DialogBox` being in accordance with MVVM in my case???

XAML parts of code:

```
<Button Command="{Binding ElementName=SaveFileDB, Path=Show}" > 
    <Button.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Style="{StaticResource styleToolTip}" >
            <TextBlock Text="Save" Style="{StaticResource styleTextBlockTP}" />
        </ToolTip>
    </Button.ToolTip>
    <Image Source="Icon\Save.png"/>
</Button>


<local:SaveFileDialogBox x:Name="SaveFileDB" Caption="Save content to file..."
                             Filter="Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files(*.*)|*.*"
                             FilterIndex="0" DefaultExt="txt"
                             CommandFileOK="{Binding SaveAsFileCommand}" >
        <local:SaveFileDialogBox.CommandParemeter>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource parametersConverter}">
                <Binding ElementName="MainRichTextBox" />
                <Binding ElementName="SaveFileDB" Path="Show" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </local:SaveFileDialogBox.CommandParemeter>
    </local:SaveFileDialogBox>
```

SaveAsFileCommand:

```
private ICommand _SaveAsFileCommand;
public ICommand SaveAsFileCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_SaveAsFileCommand == null)
        {
            _SaveAsFileCommand = new RelayCommand(
            argument =>
                {
                    var arguments = (object[])argument;
                    DataIO.SaveAsFile(arguments[0], arguments[1]); 
                }
                );
        }
        return _SaveAsFileCommand;
    }
}
```

DataIO.SaveAsFile method:

```
    public static void SaveAsFile(object argument0, object argument1)
    {
        System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox richTB = argument0 as System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox;
        string path = (string)argument1;


        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
        {
            TextRange textRange = new TextRange(richTB.Document.ContentStart, richTB.Document.ContentEnd);
            textRange.Save(fileStream, DataFormats.Text);

        }
    }
```

RelayCommand class:

```
class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _Execute;
    private readonly Func<object, bool> _CanExecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        _Execute = execute;
        _CanExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
    {
        if (execute == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        _Execute = execute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _CanExecute == null ? true : _CanExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add
        {
            if (_CanExecute != null) CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            if (_CanExecute != null) CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _Execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

DialogBox class:

```
public abstract class DialogBox : FrameworkElement, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string parameter)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(parameter));
    }

    protected Action<object> execute = null;

    public string Caption { get; set; }

    protected ICommand show;
    public virtual ICommand Show
    {
        get
        {
            if (show == null)
                show = new RelayCommand(execute);
            return show;
        }
    }
}
```

FileDialogBox class:

```
public abstract class FileDialogBox : CommandDialogBox
{
    public bool? FileDialogResult { get; protected set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public string Filter { get; set; }
    public int FilterIndex { get; set; }
    public string DefaultExt { get; set; }

    protected Microsoft.Win32.FileDialog fileDialog = null;

    protected FileDialogBox()
    {
        execute =
            o =>
            {
                var values = (object[])o;
                RelayCommand relCom1 = (RelayCommand)values[1];

                fileDialog.Title = Caption;
                fileDialog.Filter = Filter;
                fileDialog.FilterIndex = FilterIndex;
                fileDialog.DefaultExt = DefaultExt;

                string filePath = "";

                if (FilePath != null) filePath = FilePath; else FilePath = "";
                //if (o != null) filePath = (string)o;
                //if (o != null) filePath = (string)values[1];
                if (o != null) filePath = relCom1.ToString();
                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath))
                {
                    fileDialog.InitialDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
                    fileDialog.FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                }

                FileDialogResult = fileDialog.ShowDialog();
                OnPropertyChanged("FileDialogResult");
                if (FileDialogResult.HasValue && FileDialogResult != null)
                {
                    FilePath = fileDialog.FileName;
                    OnPropertyChanged("FilePath");
                    ExecuteCommand(CommandFileOK, FilePath);
                };
            };
    }

    public static DependencyProperty CommandFileOKProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CommandFileOK", typeof(ICommand), typeof(FileDialogBox));

    public ICommand CommandFileOK
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandFileOKProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandFileOKProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

SaveFileDialogBox class:

```
public class SaveFileDialogBox : FileDialogBox
{
    public SaveFileDialogBox()
    {
        fileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume you wish to implement the dialogs yourself? Because if you would be content with the built in system dialogs and still be MVVM friendly there is always MvvmDialogs for you to use.

Comment: In this case I need to implement built in dialog boxes (exactly those from Microsoft.Win32 namespace) but I want to call them from View layer not from ViewModel or Model - and this causes the problems

Answer (score 1):

The way I handle a requirement for user input in a dialog is to use a control which goes in the view but has no UI.
I split the command to be done into two pieces.
Essentially these are show the dialog and invoke a command when you finish.
The control shows a dialog which grabs data and then invokes a command you give it via binding.
Since this is control you can bind fine and it's in the visual tree so it can get a reference to the window.

Please see confirmationrequestor in this:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/WPF-User-Notification-MVVM-98940828

That's intended for confirming the deletion of a record but the same principle can be extended to a file picker with a little modification.

From that, the command invoked once the user clicks and closes the dialogue can capture any variables you need. If you bind them:

```
private RelayCommand _confirmCommand;
public RelayCommand ConfirmCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _confirmCommand
          ?? (_confirmCommand = new RelayCommand(
               () =>
               {
                   confirmer.Caption = "Please Confirm";
                   confirmer.Message = "Are you SURE you want to delete this record?";
                   confirmer.MsgBoxButton = MessageBoxButton.YesNo;
                   confirmer.MsgBoxImage = MessageBoxImage.Warning;
                   OkCommand = new RelayCommand(
                       () =>
                       {
                           // You would do some actual deletion or something here
                           UserNotificationMessage msg = new UserNotificationMessage { Message = "OK.\rDeleted it.\rYour data is consigned to oblivion.", SecondsToShow = 5 };
                           Messenger.Default.Send<UserNotificationMessage>(msg);
                       });
                   RaisePropertyChanged("OkCommand");
                   ShowConfirmation = true;
               }));
    }
}
```

From the confirmationrequestor, invoking that command:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowConfirmDialogProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ShowConfirmDialog",
                    typeof(bool?),
                    typeof(ConfirmationRequestor),
                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null
                        , new PropertyChangedCallback(ConfirmDialogChanged)
                        )
                    { BindsTwoWayByDefault = true }
                    );
    private static void ConfirmDialogChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((bool?)e.NewValue != true)
        {
            return;
        }
        ConfirmationRequestor cr = (ConfirmationRequestor)d;
        Window parent = Window.GetWindow(cr) as Window;
        MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show(parent, cr.Message, cr.Caption, cr.MsgBoxButton, cr.MsgBoxImage);
        if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK || result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {
            if (cr.Command != null)
            {
                cr.Command.Execute(cr.CommandParameter);
            }
        }
        cr.SetValue(ShowConfirmDialogProperty, false);
    }
```